# Element in zipped for loop being skipped when removing element from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

This is my first time posting so forgive any formatting errors. I want to remove an element from one of the zipped lists I am looping through, but when I remove the element from the list the index seems to skip the next iteration.

For example you will see element 4 skipped in the code below.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i,j in zip(x,y):
    print(i,j,x,y)
    if i==3:
        x.remove(i)
```

This results in the following output.

```
1 1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2 2 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3 3 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5 5 [1, 2, 4, 5] [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Note that "i" and "j" have skipped 4 altogether. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Because you are modifying something while you iterate over it.

Comment: Because you removed `3`, which made `4` the third element, which you'd already iterated over. Don't change the length of a list while iterating over it!